# Display multiple views with merge adpter in android list view

Tags: android, android-listview, view

I have a problem where I need to display two text views in one list item.

One view shows the item, clicking on which opens the item.
The other view is a plus icon, expanding the list with its children.

I scratched my head a lot, but couldn't find a way to detect which view was selected in the list view.

Somehow, I came up with `MergeAdapter`, I followed it and added two adapters to it.
The first adapter shows actual titles, while the other just shows a plus icon.

But the list only shows the first text view, and not the plus icon.

What else do I need in `MergeAdapter` to show both the views?

Displays the title, clicking on this should open the selected title page

`

```
public class TitleAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private List<Title> navItems;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public TitleAdapter(Context context, List<Title> navItems) {
        this.layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.navItems = navItems;       
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return navItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return navItems.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return navItems.get(position).getTitleID();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = null;

        TextView textView = null;

        if(convertView == null) {
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item, parent, false);

        } else {
            view = convertView;
        }

        textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);

        Title item = (Title)getItem(position);

        textView.setText(item.getTitle());

        return view;
    }
}
```

`

Displays the + icon, clicking on it should add new entries in the list, i.e., children of the selected title

`

```
public class ExpandAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private int items;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public ExpandAdapter(Context context, int items) {
        this.layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.items = items;

    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return "+";
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = null;

        if(convertView == null) {
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item2, parent, false);

        } else {
            view = convertView;
        }

        return view;
    }
}
```

`

drawer_list_item:
`

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/textView"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:textColor="@color/dark_grey"
          android:textSize="20sp"
          android:textStyle="normal"
          style="?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
          android:text="Hi" />
```

`

drawer_list_item2:

`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/expandBtn"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:textColor="@color/dark_grey"
          android:textSize="20sp"
          android:textStyle="normal"
          style="?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
          android:text="+" />
```

`

But i can't see the plus icon!

I added it in `MergeAdapter` like this:

`

```
MergeAdapter m = new MergeAdapter();        
TitleAdapter t = new TitleAdapter(this, navItems, hasChild);
ExpandAdapter e = new ExpandAdapter(this, navItems.size());
m.addAdapter(t);
m.addAdapter(e);
```

`

Comment: can you share your sample code?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html) for this it will show a dropdown indicator of its own. You can change the icon of your choice as well. It will take only one [adapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListAdapter.html) and you can populate [child](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListAdapter.html#getChild(int,%20int)) and [parent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListAdapter.html#getGroup(int)) separately.
If the requirement is somewhat different than this please mention we can discuss.

and

If you don't want to use this you can do this with a single custom adapter and add a custom layout to it. After populating add a click listener to plus button and onClick handle the visibility of the second text item.

OR

If you want multilayer list you might want to check [this](http://code.google.com/p/tree-view-list-android/) project out. I haven't tried it, but I guess it's worth a try. The default ExpanadableListView is quite limited to support only 2 levels. You can customize that to get it to support more levels than that, but it'll be much more complex.

Comment: In my case when the user presses the '+' icon, the children are a lot, like 100s, to place them in the same list. I need to re-draw the list in this case. Also the children can have more children. So do you think Expnadable ListView could do all this?

Comment: Check the last option in the above answer but it will be a complex one.

Comment: The children items are too much to do nesting, I need to repopulate the list on + touch. I don't think tree view etc will work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

## Best example demo for ExpandableListView.

https://github.com/idunnololz/AnimatedExpandableListView